# Sanitizing database query with open input

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm trying to compare students exam query result to teacher given default answer query result. So far I've created this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string query)
{
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            if (query.ToLower().Contains("drop table") || query.ToLower().Contains("create table") || query.ToLower().Contains("update") || query.ToLower().Contains("delete") || query.ToLower().Contains("drop database"))
            {
                ViewBag.warning = "You are a bad boy";
                return View();
            }

            var conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
            int row = 0;

            var columns = new List<string>();
            var columndata = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();

                using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = query;
                    DbDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();
                        ViewBag.columncount = reader.FieldCount;

                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                columndata.Add(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
                            }
                            row++;
                        }
                    }

                    reader.Dispose();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            ViewBag.queryData = columndata;
            ViewData["RowsAffected"] = row;

            return View(columns);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
}
```

which results in Search.cshtml

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "View";
}


<textarea placeholder="@ViewBag.warning">@ViewBag.warning</textarea>

<p>@ViewBag.warning</p>
@if (ViewData["RowsAffected"] != null)
{
<p>
    Number of rows : @ViewData["RowsAffected"]
</p>
}
@if (ViewBag.columncount != null)
{
int count = ViewBag.columncount;
int count2 = count - 1;
int index = 0;
int i = 0;`
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <th>@item</th>
            }
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @while (i <= count2)
        {
            <tr>
                @while (index < ViewBag.queryData.Count && i <= count2)
                {
                    <td>
                        @ViewBag.queryData[index]
                    </td>
                    index++;
                    i++;
                }
                @{ count2 += count;
                }
                @if (index >= ViewBag.queryData.Count)
                {

                    break;
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

How to better control user(student) input when they are taking the test?

At this moment I am having trouble figuring how I should compare result from query to any other result. Should I maybe be using sql except instead of comparing results?

Comment: You aim is unclear. Make your queries parameterized stored procedure calls and then you have complete control over what gets executed.  If you must accept free-form SQL from an external source then enforce control through permissions.

Comment: It's not a nice situation you have gotten yourself into. What if I search using "drop  table ..." (two blanks) or "drop table ..." (tab). Never accept any kind of SQL from the user, especailly not student.

Comment: Now I am wondering if there is some way to preview query results without actually executing it? Or is there a way to allow only select statements? Because as I understand students only perform SELECT ... queries